# Download deleted row on client for Download Only Sync Framework

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

Is it possible in sync framework to download back the deleted row when sync mode has been set to Download Only? Actually I am working on an application where few setup tables are initially only downloaded on the client. However, when the rows are deleted from these tables, it is required to download them back to client.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the incremental sync in Sync Framework is based on what has changed since the last sync.

your destination has deleted rows but the source has not change. no change recorded on the source, no change detected on sync. and your source has no idea of what has happened on the destination as well.

assuming you're fine with other clients receiving the same update, you can do a dummy update on the source (e.g., update tableX set col1=col1). this should mark the rows as changed and will be picked up on next sync.

the sync will most likely raise a conflict because it gets an update but there is no row to update on the client. when it does, set the conflict resolution to Retry with Force Write.

Comment: Thanks JuneT for your answer. This is exactly what I had done but I was looking for some concrete way.